# SharePoint 2010 Hide Top Bar ("Site Actions") With Master Page for Unauthorized Users

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I want to hide the whole top bar in SharePoint site (including Site Actions link, search bar, etc.) and also Quick Launch menu on the left. But the thing is, I want to hide those panels only for unauthorized users, while authorized users would be able to access those links when they go to *Site Settings* page. 
Is there any way of achieving this by editing Master Page? Or maybe you could suggest other way for this?

Comment: What i understand , Unauthorized user you mean anonymous user?

Comment: Yes, exactly, because by the default, if the user hasn't reached the site in the past he (or she) is going to be unauthorized (anonymous) user. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As member @Ravindra suggested, you can use *SPSecurityTrimmedControl* - edit MasterPage file and all code for top navigation, ribbon and side navigation insert into *SPSecurityTrimmedControl* code block. For example:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="AuthenticatedUsersOnly"> 
   <!-- all HTML, CSS, JS and SharePoint controls that needs to be available to authenticated user only -->
   <div id="s4-ribbonrow">
      ...
   </div>
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPSecurity trimmed control. Below is the sample snippet

....

Now all controls inside the SPSecurityTrimmedControls will be hidden to anonymous users.